# i value not iterating in Callback functions

Tags: javascript, json, callback

This may be a question without any R&D but I am on a busy schedule and very new to these callback functions, The problem is I am getting a json payload from a webapp and I am trying to parse it , so this payload has a array of objects , but when i use this in my script i am getting only the last array index value.
below is the code and attached console output for reference , please suggest where i am going wrong

```
var case1 = payload.Case;
var i=0;
for(i=0;i<case1.length;i++)
{
     var c1 = case1[i];
     c1.retrieveAttributes(function(){
            console.log(i+ " i");
             console.dir(c1.attributes);
     });
}
```

The i value in console is always 6.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're having an issue with 'closure' scope. Try passing 'i' into your function like this.

```
var case1 = payload.Case;
var i=0;
for(i=0;i<case1.length;i++)
{
     var c1 = case1[i];
     c1.retrieveAttributes(function(i){
            console.log(i+ " i");
             console.dir(c1.attributes);
     });
}
```

That should preserve the true value of 'i'.

Comment: Are you sure `retrieveAttributes()` supports passing an index to the callback it takes?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi call back will not take any arguments